# How can I iterate over values of a dictionary in an efficient way?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm running a school assignment matching algorithm using dictionaries. All the process of the algorithm is relatively efficient, except for the part where I need to export the results to a `.csv`.

`students` is a dictionary with 483.070 pairs of key-value. The key is an integer with an id, and the value is a Student class object that I create. Actually, to export results I'm using the following methods.

```py
def parse_student_match_information(student: Student) -> int:
    if student.assigned_vacancy is None:
        return 0
    return student.assigned_vacancy.program_id

def get_assignation_output(students: dict)-> pd.DataFrame:
    result = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Student_ID', 'Program_ID', 'Grade_ID'])
    for student in students.values():
        program_id = parse_student_match_information(student)
        result = result.append({'Student_ID': student.id, 'Program_ID': program_id, 'Grade_ID': student.grade}, ignore_index = True)
    return result.sort_values('Grade_ID')
```

It took more than an hour to produce this `pd.DataFrame`. Any suggestion is welcome!

Comment: How much time is spent in each part of the code? In the iteration of the students, the parsing of the students, the append to the dataframe, and the sort. Identify which is taking the longest.

Comment: If you're looking for suggestions to improve working code, then this probably belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you don't want to append to a DataFrame but instead create it from an iterable, a better way would be as shown below.

```
def parse_student_match_information(student: Student) -> int:
    if student.assigned_vacancy is None:
        return 0
    return student.assigned_vacancy.program_id

def get_assignation_output(students: dict) -> Iterable[dict]:
    for student in students.values():
        program_id = parse_student_match_information(student)
        result = {'Student_ID': student.id, 'Program_ID': program_id, 'Grade_ID': student.grade}
        yield result

def make_df(rows: Iterable[dict]) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=['Student_ID', 'Program_ID', 'Grade_ID'])
    df.sort_values(by=['Grade_ID'])
    return df
```

This way you create the DataFrame from *all* the rows at once and then sort it once at the very end as opposed to each iteration. You should see improvements in terms of performance from this.

Comment: just out of curiosity, what did this cut the time down to?

Comment: From 1 hour to 15-20 seconds!